# Will a SATA II I/O card drive SATA I drives

Tags: sata

Will I be able to use my SATA I drives with a SATA II PCI controller card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but only at SATA I speeds.

Comment: That's 150 mb/s right?